# Is it at all possible to include background colors when copying selections from Firefox to the system clipboard?

Tags: firefox, formatting, clipboard

My exhaustive web searches suggest not, as do my searches in about:config for the words 'background', 'clipboard', 'color' and 'copy'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is posted to the clipboard as plain text (CF_TEXT) then no.  If it's a rich format like HTML or RTF, then yes it should be possible.  This assumes that this is a programming question, and my certainty of that is waning.